# Angular Material struggling adjust width of dialog elements

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm working on a text dialog that I'll be reusing frequently in my app.  My text dialog is fairly simple, it has a header, a message to display above the text input, the text input area, and an "Ok" and "Cancel" button.

From what I can see, the simplest way to adjust the width of a dialog is to pass it in with the MatDialogConfig object when calling open on the dialog, as so:

```
openDialog() {
    var params = {
        data: {
            // my data getting pased into the dialog
        },
        width: "600px"
    }

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TextDialog, params);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => { //do something after close });
}
```

This causes the window to increase to the preferred size, however all my elements inside the dialog's template do not increase in size.  If I do not adjust the width when calling the window and I inspect the window's elements, the width is 228.27.  The text input's width is 180.

When I increase the width of the element to 600, the input stays the same width.  I've tried inspecting the dialog.  Everything sits in the mat-dialog-container, including the div.mat-dialog-container element, both of those are the correct width.  However, everything from the mat-form-field and below all still hold the original 180 pixel width.  I can manually adjust the width with:

```
mat-form-field {
    width: 600px;
}
```

But if I try using inherit or auto it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't think of this sooner, but setting the width to 100% fixed the issue for me without any wizardry.

In my css file,

```
mat-form-field {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This was all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

When using dynamic styling in Angular, use [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle).

This will allow you to pass expression-driven styling, thus letting Angular answer all the questions related to how and when to update the styles in the DOM.